# How to add an if/else condition to echo

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add an if/else condition to echo in order to display on say. How can i do this?

```
<?php if ( is_object_in_term( $loop->post->ID, 'countries', 'germany' ) ) {
          echo '<div class="speaker-flag"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/flag-for-germany.svg"></div>';
      } else if ( is_object_in_term( $loop->post->ID, 'countries', 'switzerland' ) ) {
          echo '<div class="speaker-flag"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/flag-for-switzerland.svg"></div>';
      } ?>

echo '<li></li>'
```

```js
$germany_flag = "/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/flag-for-germany.svg";
$swiss_flag = "/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/flag-for-switzerland.svg";
$is_germany = is_object_in_term( $loop->post->ID, 'countries', 'germany' );

'<li>
      <div class="speaker-flag"><img src="'.$is_germany ? $germany_flag : $swiss_flag .'"></div>
</li>'
```

Comment: Either use the _ternary operator_, or break it into multiple parts - echo first part, do if/else to echo the middle part, and then echo the last part after.

Comment: Could you provide code on how to implement this?

Comment: No, I will not provide code on something this basic, without you making an actual attempt first. We should rather not have to teach _syntax_ here to begin with.

Comment: I tried to do this, but I didn't succeed. I have attached the code to the question.

Comment: Didn't succeed how? Is there a specific error? It looks like you simply forgot to echo the last string, but maybe there's something else too. Always explain your problem clearly with specifics.

Comment: There is also a stackexchange specifically for wordpress..  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com